# How to store credentials in docker build secrets (not swarm) like docker secrets in docker swarm?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Currently, I’m using a Linux OS and having an issue with Docker build secrets, the credential file used for mounting still exists on the local machine during and after the build process.

I want to ask if there’s a way to store credentials similar to Docker secrets in Docker Swarm? or Do we have any way to protect the credential file on the local machine?

Here’s where I referenced:

https://docs.docker.com/build/building/secrets/#sources
https://docs.docker.com/reference/dockerfile/#run---mounttypesecret

I've searched a lot but I can't find any way to protect the credential file in local machine.